# Common items between all the keys of a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary of "259136 keys" and each of those keys, have 1 or more than one values.

My objective is "to find keys that have at least one value common with another key in the list of keys?"

I have tried different ways to deal with this problem but I was looking for a faster solution. I tried

1. for each key compare with the 259135 keys to check the above condition
2. reversing the dictionary from key value to value key, so now the value becomes key and this way I will have two dictionaries and I can go to first one and based on the values in the first one pull out all the values from the second one.

Comment: What were the results of your attempts?

Comment: How can one key in your dictionary have more than one value? Or are your dictionary values lists (tuples, sets, any container) which may contain one or more values?

Comment: Is it important that you know which key the key has a value in common with?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com (where they will expect to *see* the code)

Comment: I am trying to post my code and output but having trouble editing them. Is there anyway I can upload them as a text file? Please comment.

Comment: Yes  Hyperboreus my dictionary value is a list.

Comment: Yes Johm Don it is necessary to know which key the key has a value common with

Comment: @mparida: since every dictionary key is associated with exactly one value (in your case, apparently of type list), saying "each of those keys, have 1 or more than one values" isn't right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dict of sets:

```
d={    'k1': [1,2,3],
       'k2': [2],
       'k3': [10],
       'k4': [3,2]
    }

com_keys={}
for k, v in d.items():
    for e in v:
        com_keys.setdefault(e, set()).add(k)    

print com_keys   
# {1: set(['k1']), 10: set(['k3']), 3: set(['k1', 'k4']), 2: set(['k2', 'k1', 'k4'])}
```

Then if you only want the ones that have more than one key in common, just filter with a dict comprehension (or the like for older Pythons):

```
>>> {k:v for k,v in com_keys.items() if len(v)>1 }
{2: set(['k2', 'k1', 'k4']), 3: set(['k1', 'k4'])}
```

It get a *little* more challenging if your dict is a non-homogenous combination of containers that support iteration (lists, tuples, etc) with 'single items' that either do not support iteration (ints, floats) or things that you do not want to iterate with a `for` loop (strings, unicode, other dicts, etc)

For example, assume you have a combination of lists and 'single items' that are ints and strings:

```
import collections

d={    'k1': [1,2,3],
       'k2': 2,
       'k3': [10],
       'k4': [3,2],
       'k5': 'string',
       'k6': ['string',2]
    }

com_keys={}
for k, v in d.items():
    if not isinstance(v, basestring) and isinstance(v, collections.Iterable):   
        for e in v:
            com_keys.setdefault(e, set()).add(k)    
    else:        
        com_keys.setdefault(v, set()).add(k)

print com_keys
# {1: set(['k1']), 10: set(['k3']), 3: set(['k1', 'k4']), 2: set(['k2', 'k1', 'k6', 'k4']), 'string': set(['k6', 'k5'])}
print {k:v for k,v in com_keys.items() if len(v)>1 }   
# {2: set(['k2', 'k1', 'k6', 'k4']), 3: set(['k1', 'k4']), 'string': set(['k6', 'k5'])}
```